# reading text file and putting some characters in lists

Tags: python, list, text-files

My objective is to transform this text in a textfile (all in 1 line):

```
a b s d p
5 4 3 3 2
..........
....pp..s.
........s.
.a......s.
.a.....b..
.a.....b..
.a.....b..
.a.ddd.b..
..........
..........
```

And have an output: [['a', 'b', 's', 'd', 'p'],[5, 4, 3, 3, 2]]
But I get the following error:
    ship_characters.append(str(char))
MemoryError

Here is my code:

```
def read_ship_data(game_file):

    ship_characters = []
    ship_sizes = []

    game = open(game_file, 'r')
    for line in game:
        for char in line:
            while char != '.':
                if char.isalpha():
                    ship_characters.append(str(char))
                elif char.isnumeric():
                    ship_sizes.append(int(char))
    return [ship_characters , ship_sizes]
```

Comment: `while char != '.':` infinite loop incoming. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: why would the while statement lead to an infinite loop? Should it not stop at the first '.'

Comment: Do you only want characters in the first two lines in the result?

Comment: @GabrielJoséLabrousse: what do you mean by _"all in 1 line"_? Is there only one line in your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have identified the reason for the memory error: an infinite loop.

Assuming that you require the first 2 lines from the file here is a better way to do it:

```
def read_ship_data(game_file):
    with open(game_file) as game_file:
        return [line.split() for line in (next(game_file), next(game_file))]
```

This just reads the first 2 lines from the file (with `next(file)`), and splits the lines in a list comprehension, which is returned from the function.

If you need to convert the values from the second line to integers:

```
def read_ship_data(game_file):
    with open(game_file) as game_file:
        return [next(game_file).split(),  [int(x) for x in next(game_file).split()]]
```

Comment: However I am confused about how the program knows where to stop. My initial thought, was that the program would stop at the '.'. However here you do no mention of it. Would you mind explaning? @mhawke

Comment: @GabrielJoséLabrousse: the code reads the file one line at a time, not one character at a time. Calling `next()` on an open text file will return one line. Calling it again will return the next line. Because the data that you present is line oriented, it's possible to just read each line and split it as shown. Thus the `.` is not required.

Comment: very interesting! makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are looping infinitely on the first character and appending it to your list. Your while loop will never stop since `'a' != '.'` will always be true.

If you just want the 2 first lines and the format will never change, you should use something simpler:

```
def read_ship_data(game_file):
    with open(game_file, 'r') as file:
        ship_characters = file.readline().strip().split()
        ship_sizes = file.readline().strip().split()
        ship_sizes = [int(i) for i in ship_sizes]

    return [ship_characters, ship_sizes]
```

Comment: Why do you think the OP only wants two lines?

Comment: @wwii he wants to stop at the '.' character. And look at the output he wants.

Comment: I dont understand what tells the program to stop. This does give me the result I expect. What is the logic given you do not use the '.'

Comment: It's just reading 2 lines because we call `readline()` only 2 times. The `with` statement will make sure everything is closed properly after.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping forever:

```
for char in line:
    while char != '.':
        if char.isalpha():
            ship_characters.append(str(char))
        elif char.isnumeric():
            ship_sizes.append(int(char))
```

You set the value of `char` for one iteration through `line`, then you stay in your `while` loop as long as that value isn't `'.'` - but no where in the `while` loop do you change the value of `char`.  That happens outside of the while loop, when it gets to the next cycle in the for loop.

It seems like you want to remove the `while` loop and instead have `if char != '.':` maybe?

Edit: Actually there's no need to catch `'.'` separately - you're already testing using `isalpha()` and `isnumeric()` - note that you want `isdigit()` if you're in Python 2.x and not using unicode - and a `'.'` returns False on both of those.  So you can do it like this:

```
for char in line:
    if char.isalpha():
        ship_characters.append(str(char))
    elif char.isnumeric():
        ship_sizes.append(int(char))
    else:
        pass
        #do something for non-letter and non-number values if you want
```

Comment: You should add a solution with ```if char == '.' : continue``` as a substitute for the ```while``` statement.